# unixODBC connection with Teradata

Tags: python, redhat, teradata, unixodbc

Has anyone ever got this to work on RHEL?
I have successfully installed Teradata 14.10 on my box. BTEQ works fine and I've tested the Teradata odbc connection using tdxodbc, which also successfully works. My problem is I want to connect via Python using it's pyodbc. I keep getting some cryptic error message:

```
[******@sdc01cunx09 ~]$ python helloworld.py
Hello World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MyTD; UID=*****; PWD=*****")
pyodbc.Error: ('200', '[200] [unixODBC][eaaa[DCTrdt rvr o nuhifraint o n (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

Please help!! This is driving me N-U-T-S!!

Comment: I can't help you with this issue, but there's a brand new http://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module You might give it a try...

Comment: Can you paste your odbcinst.ini file in your post. I did this a while back so I feel your pain. pyodbc is very picky about this DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=localhost;UID=dbc;PWD=dbc;QUIETMODE=YES;

Comment: Ignore quiet mode but make sure you have DBCNAME all caps spelled exactly and your driver that is selected. The DSN I had working but trashed it when I put R drivers on the box :/.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings read this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Teradata Python module rather than using unixODBC. You can use Teradata ODBC drivers directly with it, you may consider Teradata REST API as well

Teradata Pyhton module: https://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module